# Can I cast one Eloquent model to another?

Tags: php, laravel, oop, eloquent

In eloquent you can have different models operating on a same table.
So, is it possible to switch an object from one Model to another in a runtime.
Assuming that we have three classes:

```
Product extends Model
ProductSet extends Product
SimpleProduct extends Product
```

The difference between ProductSet and a SimpleProduct is column `complex` which has 'true' in it for a ProductSet and 'false' for a SimpleProduct.

ProductSet and a SimpleProduct models have Scopes applied to them so that `ProductSet::all()` will get only sets, and `SimpleProduct::all()` will get only a simple products.

Parent model however allow us to get both types of products via `Product::all()`
so, is it possible to go through all instances of Product class and switch them to their higher level models at runtime based on a value of property `complex` ?

Comment: sorry, I can't completely understand, maybe I need to know your full model

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already extending the class which holds the same **props** as the parent. You can loop over any `product` collection and get all the attributes through `getAttributes()` method and pass to the parent. Because each of your model is extending Eloquent `Model` which accepts attribute in the `constructor` and **fills** its attribute.

Following example extends the default `User` class and converts back to the **Parent** class

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Admin extends User {}
```

Get all `Admins` and convert them to `User`

```
$admins = \App\Admin::all();

$users = [];
foreach ($admins as $admin) {
    $users[] = new \App\User($admin->getAttributes());
}
dd(collect($users));
```

Comment: Thanks! I somehow thought that it's not acceptable to pass an id property directly to the constructor. Checked it out in tinker, works fine. Although all the fields should be mass-assignable or you'll need to copy them all by hand.

Downvotes are not from me

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do that, Based on the **prop** you have to create object of that specific class